# iOS-charts bar chart with negative values

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using the great iOS-charts pod for doing my graphics. Now I have to display a bar chart with y-value in a range from -120 to 0. When I add those values, I get the bars displays from the top - 0 - to the bottom.
What I am looking for is a way to let the bar be drawn from the bottom of the chart up to it's value, because 0 means a lot for the application while -120 means nothing. So I would like to get a big bar for 0 and nothing for -120 like this.

0

```
 X
 X        X
 X   X    X
```

-120 x   X    X

Any idea how I can achieve this behavior?

Thanks a lot
Andy

Comment: I found out, that I have to add a value to make the neg value positive and then I can change the Labels with the formatter accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set logical values for the correct visibility - and the use a formatter for showing the values as negative values.

In Charts 3.0 it is easier to format the values.

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you tell me how to format values for negatives? I am trying to show positive as well as negative values. I am using charts 3.1 on xcode 9.4.1